# Graphviz change edge direction

Tags: linked-list, graphviz, hackmd

I use `graphviz` on `hackmd` and draw a graph like this
[image]

my code is:

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    node [color=black,shape=record]
    node0 [label="{<data>node 0|<next>}"]
    node1 [label="{<data>node 1|<next>}"]
    new_node [label="{<data>new_node|<next>}"]
    null0 [shape=none, label="NULL"]
    null1 [shape=none, label="NULL"]
    head [shape=none, label="head"]
    ptr [shape=none, label="ptr"]
    indirect [shape=none]
    
    head->ptr
    indirect->node0:next [constraint=false headport=s tailport=n];
    ptr->node0
    node0:next:c->node1 [arrowhead=normal, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
    node1:next:c -> null0 [tailclip=false, arrowtail=dot, dir=both]
    
    
    new_node:next:c->null1 [arrowhead=normal, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
    {rank=same; indirect node1;}
}
```

I want `node0` and indirect on the same rank. However, when I change

```
{rank=same; indirect node1;} -> {rank=same; indirect node0;}
```

they will have error message: `"Error: lost indirect node0 edge"`
The actual graph I want:

[image]

Comment: Interesting. With 2version 2.40.1 I get "Warning: flat edge between adjacent nodes one of which has a record shape - replace records with HTML-like labels
  Edge indirect -> node0
Error: lost indirect node0 edge" and the edge is gone. With version 2.38.0 I get "Warning: Unable to reclaim box space in spline routing for edge "indirect" -> "node0". Something is probably seriously wrong." and there is an edge present. Maybe worth to check the GraphViz issues / repository at https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/

Answer (score 0):

Change your layout to use html style labels instead of shape=record

```
digraph G {
    rankdir=LR
    node [color=black shape=none margin=0 height=.3 ]
    node0 [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td port="data">node 0</td><td port="next">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>>]
    node1 [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td port="data">node 1</td><td port="next">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>>]
    new_node [label=<<table border="0" cellborder="1" cellspacing="0"><tr><td port="data">new_node</td><td port="next">&nbsp;</td></tr></table>>]
    null0 [shape=none, label="NULL"]
    null1 [shape=none, label="NULL"]
    head [shape=none, label="head"]
    ptr [shape=none, label="ptr"]
    indirect [shape=none]
    
    head->ptr
    indirect->node0:next [constraint=false headport=s tailport=n];
    ptr->node0
    node0:next:c->node1 [arrowhead=normal, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
    node1:next:c -> null0 [tailclip=false, arrowtail=dot, dir=both]
    
    
    new_node:next:c->null1 [arrowhead=normal, arrowtail=dot, dir=both, tailclip=false];
    {rank=same indirect node0}
}
```

[image]